# Python return value must be written twice?

Tags: python

```
def simulate_tournament(teams):

    if len(teams) == 1:
        return teams[0]['team']
    else:
        teams = simulate_round(teams)
        simulate_tournament(teams)
    return teams[0]['team']
```

```
 return teams[0]['team']
```

My code won't run without this final line outside of the if else statements. But I don't get why I need this? Wouldn't the function iterate until `len(teams) == 1` whereby the function will return teams?

Comment: The function with recurse until `len(teams) == 1`, and return, but then the call above that will return `None`.

Comment: Rather than recursion, you should probably just use `while len(teams) != 1: teams = simulate_round(teams)`.  Once the loop exits, *then* use the `return` statement.

Comment: I guess I'm just trying to understand why it doesn't work. @Loocid what does "the call above that" mean?

Comment: The `else` block has no `return` statement. Why not have `return simulate_tournament(teams)` rather than `simulate_tournament(teams)` ? What you currently have discards any return value.

Comment: I'm trying to understand from your response to the previous comments, to see what your code's intent is. You used the word _iterate_ but there are no loops in this code. Since you are calling a function from within itself, this is _recursion_. As @chepner says, you should use a `while` loop until `simulate_round` reduces the `teams` down to just 1. That 1 team is when you can finally call return. The function as you have it will run `simulate_round`, probably reducing `teams`, then call `simulate_tournament` again, but I would bet at that point, `teams` is probably not yet down to 1.

Answer (score 1):

As your else block has no `return` statement or any object to hold the data, for recursive call it is calling and getting Nothing back, because of this you are getting no result

```
def simulate_tournament(teams):
    if len(teams) == 1:
        result= teams[0]['team']
    else:
        teams = simulate_round(teams)
        result = simulate_tournament(teams)
    return result
```

Comment: What happens to `data` in your solution above?

Comment: @BenY it should be `result`, i have named it `data` earlier and somehow missed this one while renaming,

Comment: There's no need to initialize `result = None`; `result` gets set in either branch of the `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return teams[0][“teams”] because recursion requires the knowledge of the last output so it can be the next input. Try tracing out the flow of your code where the return variable is the next input.  Ideally, you should return simulate_tournament(teams). This guide might help: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/recursion

Answer (score 0):

I am making assumptions about the functions you don't have explained.

1. `simulate_round(teams)` takes a list of teams and reduces them (by half).
2. `simulate_tournament(teams)` is the actual running of the tournament.

I think in this case, the tournament is more a superset of round, and that you don't have multiple tournaments, but you have multiple rounds. With these assumptions, this is my proposed fix.

```
def simulate_tournament(teams):
    while len(teams) > 1:
        teams = simulate_round(teams)  # Run the round, returning all the winners
    if not teams:
         return None  # If we ran a round and NOBODY won, the result is None
    return teams[0]['team']  # This means there was exactly 1 winner, so return that
```